# Number of unique values taken by a variable for a subset of the data, within a loop

Tags: count, nested-loops, stata, coding-efficiency

I am writing some code in Stata, but the current iteration is quite inefficient. I know how I would change things if I were to write this in python/pandas to make things better, but am unsure how to do this/if it is possible in Stata. For workflow reasons I need to keep this code in the Stata language.

The basic problem is that I have two categorical variables, `cata` and `catb`. Each can take on several thousand values. I'd like to reduce the number of categories in `catb` by keeping a category only if at least two observations occur in the same `cata`. I have used `egen group()` to ensure that the categories are numeric, and the maximum value is the number of categories for both variables.

My current code looks like this:

```
foreach var in cata catb {
    qui sum `var'
    local `var'_max = r(max)
}
local list
forvalues i=1/`cata_max' {
    if mod(`i',10)==0 di `i' " of " `cata_max'
    forvalues i=j/`catb_max' {
        qui count if cata==`i' & catb==`j'
        if r(N)>1 local list `list' `j'
    }
}
gen mask=0
foreach i in `list' {
    replace mask=1 if catb==`i'
}
replace catb=-1 if mask==0
```

I believe this code runs and will work, but I'm estimating completion in ~16 hours for data with ~100k observations.

The problematic piece of this is the nested loop, as I am looping over all possible values of `catb`, even though only about 10ish show up (`cata` average size is 20-30). I would like to select only the relevant portion of `catb` to loop over in the nested loop, rather than all possible values of `catb`. In pandas/python I'd do something like:

```
val_list=[]
for i in df['cata'].unique():
    df_temp=df[df['cata']==i]
    rel_vals=df_temp['catb'].unique()
    for j in rel_vals:
        if len(df_temp[df_temp['catb']])>1:
            val_list+=[j]
```

Which, while not great code, illustrates the idea of looping over only the relevant values of `catb`. This should reduce the time taken in the second loop by ~300X, which will yield a substantial speedup even if there's some overhead to finding the unique values.

How do I get only the unique values of a variable within this loop structure? My searches yield only posts like [this](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/number-of-distinct-observations/), which is a roundabout way to calculate unique values of a variable (and does not lend itself well to unique values of a subset of the data as in my situation).

Example:

```
index   cata    catb    catb2
0       A       1       -1
1       B       2       2
2       C       1       -1
3       A       2       2
4       B       2       2
5       C       2       2
```

Explanation: `catb2` is the new version of `catb`, which replaces category "1" because there is no `cata` in which multiple "1"s appear. Category "2" remains untouched, because it shows up twice in `cata` B.

Comment: Not tactful to malign a document I wrote. Regardless of that, the FAQ references a 2008 paper with a detailed discussion of distinct observations with respect to one or several variables.

Comment: A miniature data example would help here.

Comment: @NickCox To be fair, it's a document that has helped me several times, but it's applicability here does not seem as straightforward to me. I will include a miniature example - while your answer is not quite what I had in mind, it may suffice for my problem.

Comment: Generous of you... Insert smiley as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to `drop` combinations of `cata` and `catb` that occur just once:

```
 bysort cata catb: drop if _N == 1
```

Comment: This is simpler than what I had in mind, and vectorized much better. I think there is a way to move from this idea to what I had in mind - at least more efficiently than my original loop.

Comment: Good. (I have respect for Python but don't know it. Life is short.)

Answer (score 0):

I think even looping only over the observed values of `catb` would be a relatively inefficient approach. I suggest using the `duplicates` command (which for scale I suggest using the `gduplicates` command found in the very helpful gtools package--`ssc install gtools`). Here is an example of implementation:

```
clear
input index str1(cata) catb    
0 "A" 1       
1 "B" 2       
2 "C" 1       
3 "A" 2       
4 "B" 2       
5 "C" 2       
end

// Tags unique pairs of cata and catb with N-1
// i.e. a value of 2 means that there are 3 observed pairs given cata and catb
duplicates tag cata catb, gen(observed_pairs)

// The maximum unique pairs that catb is a part of
egen catb_max = max(observed_pairs), by(catb)

// Will make new catb2 that is -1 if a catb at most 1 in each cat a
gen catb2 = catb
replace catb2 = -1 if catb_max == 0
```